# Stripe Error Message 405 - "append .json to uri to use rest api"

Tags: json, firebase

I'm using Stripe, and trying to send a test webhook to my URL and database hosted by Firebase. When I "send test webhook," I get the following error message in the Stripe Console:

Test Webhook Error: 405

"append .json to your request URI to use the rest API"

My code is a direct copy of the tutorial: https://github.com/GaryH21/Stripe-Webhooks-Tutorial/blob/master/functions/index.js

Here is the code of my index.js:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const stripe = require("stripe")(functions.config().keys.webhooks);
const admin = require('firebase-admin')
admin.initializeApp();
const endpointSecret = functions.config().keys.signing;



exports.events = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {

    let sig = request.headers["stripe-signature"];
    try {
        let event = stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(request.rawBody, sig, endpointSecret)
        return admin.database().ref('/events').push(event)
            .then((snapshot) => {
                return response.json({ received: true, ref: snapshot.ref.toString() })
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.error(err)
                return response.status(500).end() // error saving to database
            })
    } catch (err) {
        return response.status(400).end() // signing signature failed
    }

})


exports.exampleDataBaseTrigger = functions.database.ref('/events/{eventId}').onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
    return console.log({
        eventId: context.params.eventid,
        data: snapshot.val()
    })
})
```

The only time in the tutorial and in my code that .json is used is in the line: `return response.json({ received: true, ref: snapshot.ref.toString() })`

Should I be appending .json onto "request" somewhere, such as in request.RawBody?

It isn't a problem with the signing keys, as that would give the 400 Error message, which I already dealt with and fixed.

I would be happy to share the code of other files in my app, but as far as I can tell none of the rest is relevant to the problem. Thank you very much.

Comment: That error is coming out of calls to Firebase URL's. I'd suggest seeing if you need to append the `.json` in `admin.database().ref('/events')` and/or `functions.database.ref('/events/{eventId}')`.

Comment: That it comes from calls to Firebase makes perfect sense, and helps me understand it. Still, appending `.json` anywhere in the line `admin.database().ref('/events')` will give the same result, and appending it in `functions.database.ref('/events/{eventId}')` results in an error during firebase deployment saying that `functions.json` is not a function.